# How use typeorm entity manager with ViewEntity on Nestjs?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, view, nestjs, typeorm

My project is on Nestjs framework, and I'm using postgres with Typeorm.
I have a ViewEntity in order to retrieve calculted fields based on different tables. This view is built with a QueryBuilder. When I sync my database, I see my view in my postgres database, with relevant data.

Now I'm trying to find inside this view.

When I add the class of this view in `entities` Typeorm configuration, I get this issue: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createValueMap' of undefined`

When I remove the class of the entities Typeorm configuration, I get this : `No metadata for "MyView" was found.`

For classic entities, I don't import them in Typeorm configuration but in `TypeOrmModule.forFeature` (I import custom repository for must of them).

My database module import Typeorm like that:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: host,
      port: 5432,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      database: db,
      connectTimeoutMS: 20000,
      extra: {
        max: 50,
      },
      synchronize: true,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
    }),
```

My ormconfig.ts file:

```
module.exports = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: 5432,
  username: username,
  password: password,
  database: db,
  entities: ['dist/**/*{.entity,.view.entity}{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: true,
};
```

My service file which try to find in my view:

```
...
  constructor(
    @InjectEntityManager('default')
    private entityManager: EntityManager,
  ) {
  }

...
    public async findOne(id: number) {
        const privateLivingArea = await this.entityManager.findOne(MyView, id);
        return privateLivingArea;
    }
...
```

What am I doing wrong ? Should I import this view somewhere else ? Is the Typeorm view compatible with Nestjs framework ?

Comment: I resolved this issue by only implementing `find`/`findOne` methods from default repository of my view.

Comment: Could you show an example of your solution?